# Environment variable JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD returns null even if specified

Tags: java, variables, process, jvm, environment

I'm trying to detect whether program runs on the first thread or not. (due to lwjgl). I followed [this tutorial](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/starting-jvm-on-mac-with-xstartonfirstthread-programmatically/37697/view.html).

For some reason this code returns always null even I run it with -XstartOnFirstThread option

```
    String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0];
    // get environment variable on whether XstartOnFirstThread is enabled
    String env = System.getenv("JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_" + pid);

    System.out.println("env: "+env);
```

Comment: The result of `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` is actually unspecified. Did you verify that it still has the expected format, i.e. the decimal pid before the `@`? Starting with Java 9, you can use the more reliable `ProcessHandle.current().pid()`. Another point to consider, is to output the entire result of `System.getenv()`, to see what’s actually available.